# ASP.NET and YouTube privacy

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, youtube-api

I'm currently building a website which contains video material from a YouTube channel. The users of the website should be able to watch the embedded YouTube videos, but the videos must not, under any circumstances, be shared across the web.

Is there any way to achieve this? I could go for the unlisted-solution where all of the videos are unlisted, but this wouldn't cut it because you are able to share the link to other users. Then there is the "private" option on videos, but that seems "only" to work on manually setting the permissions for certain YouTube accounts.

Anyone got a hint on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible because if you have the video *private* your website cant use them too, only if **YOU** are logged in on YouTube.

The source of your website is visible to every visitor, so if it would possible the visitor can catch the link and access the video / share the link.

So in short. It is not possible, there are no other options like a **referrer** filter or something.

Comment: Hi dknaack, I guess that was the answer I expected :/ Ah well, have to go with the unlisted solution then. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

A quick note: I found that if you buy the Pro subscription on Vimeo.com, you are able to secure your videos by a given domain.

Just for future reference :-)

/ Bo